# What's the state of the art for ensuring all Swing calls are executed on the EDT?

Tags: java, swing, java-8

There are some old blog posts and Stack Overflow questions (5-10 years old) that talk about how to do this.  At least one reference is made by Alexander Potochkin to an "easier" way to debug Swing in Java 1.7 (and we're at Java 1.8 right now) in his blog post (in 2006): https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/02/16/debugging-swing-final-summary

So what is this easier way to debug swing applications?  What do we do today to check that a complex application is correctly using the EDT?

This question is a somewhat duplicate of [How to check a Swing application for correct use of the EDT (Event DIspatch Thread)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760204/how-to-check-a-swing-application-for-correct-use-of-the-edt-event-dispatch-thre) and [Swing verify code on Event Dispatch Thread at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014972/swing-verify-code-on-event-dispatch-thread-at-runtime), but neither of those have the answer to the part about "easier in Java 1.7" as stated in Alex's 2006 blog post.

I'm really looking for the latest answer to this question and how Java 1.7 made it easier.

Comment: `ThreadCheckingRepaintManager` is illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7787998/230513).